# using new value entered in textbox inside listview for validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am developing ecommerce website in asp.net C#. In my cart page I have given option to add gift voucher on each product. After cart page gets load successfully then user can enter voucher code on each product which then checks in table. If coupon code exist for that particular product id then it will get applied. I tried following code to get value from textbox. But user entered value not getting.

OnListviewItemCommand I have used following.

```
if (e.CommandName == "apply code") {
    try {
        int id = e.CommandArgument;
        TextBox coupon = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("itemCoupon");
        Label productID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("item_ID");
        string couponDiscount = "0";

        string couponCode = string.Empty;
        string itemID = string.Empty;
        try {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(coupon.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(productID.Text)) {
                string str = "SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE code IN('" + coupon.Text + "') and item_ID IN('" + productID.Text + "')";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con);
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
                couponCode = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("coupon_code");
                itemID = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("item_ID");
                if (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) {
                    if (couponCode == coupon.Text && itemID == productID.Text) {
                        couponDiscount = ds.Tables(0)("coupon_discount").ToString;
                    } else {
                        couponDiscount = "0";
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Update - Listview Markup

```
<asp:ListView ID="cartItemsList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="item_ID">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="my-item">
                                        <div class="item-pic">
                                            <asp:Image ID="itmPic" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("item_pic") %>' />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="item-details">
                                            <asp:Label ID="itemName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("item_name") %>' CssClass="item-name"></asp:Label>
                                            <div class="single-redeem">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="itemCoupon" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="itemRedeemButton" runat="server" Text="apply" placeholder="Promo Code" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("item_ID") %>' CommandName="apply code"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
```

My only problem is I need to get value from textbox.

Comment: did you try TextBox leave event?

Comment: @Badiparmagi The textbox is inside Listview. How Can I use Leave event in this?

Comment: did you put `runat = "server"` tag in your TextBox control?

Comment: @Badiparmagi obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine. I tested it and I get the value of the TextBox in code behind. Maybe the problem is in the database connection/query?
The simplified snippet below is not a solution, but to show you it does work.

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CommandName="apply code" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("itemID") %>' />
            <asp:TextBox ID="itemCoupon" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="item_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemID") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "apply code")
        {
            TextBox coupon = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("itemCoupon");
            Label productID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("item_ID");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(coupon.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(productID.Text))
            {
                //this works
                Response.Write(coupon.Text + "___" + productID.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Just make sure you bind the ListView data in an `IsPostBack` check.

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ListView1.DataSource = yourSource;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: I don't wan't to load value in textbox. User enters value in textbox & click apply. So whatever code user entered in textbox gets checked in table whether it exist or not & if it exist it will get apply.

Comment: I put my listview code inside postback but still not working. This is the value of textbox I am getting when I debugged code {System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox}

Comment: On which line in your snippet do you get that string, and what does your ListView markup look like? PS this line is incorrect `int id = e.CommandArgument;`. You need to cast or convert the CommandArgument.

Comment: What about this line? `Label productID = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("item_ID");`. It does not exist in your snippet (maybe "itemName"?) and will trow an error when you evaluate it with `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productID.Text)`. It is caught by the try-catch that does nothing.

Comment: But what is the problem in this line? TextBox coupon = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("itemCoupon"); It won't get values entered by  user in coupon(textbox created at runtime)?

Comment: Nothing. That line is correct. Comment out your entire `ListView1_ItemCommand` and try mine. If that works rebuild from there. Sometimes it helps to start over.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125518/discussion-between-sun-and-vdwwd).

Comment: Tested it on 2 different machines. It does work. Try it on a new page with just my code in front and back.

Comment: Right. I was missing ItemID control in Listview. Thanks it solved